# Printing garbage information in R

Tags: r

I am facing some wired problem in R. When I try to print values from column named 'who' from CSV file it prints extra information (probably garbage) which is even not present in the file. Here is the information I am reading from file

```
bug_id  who
1141327 dtownsend
1141327 dtownsend
1142623 wkocher
1142623 wkocher
1143179 jorge
1143179 jorge
1144222 dtownsend
1144222 dtownsend
1144493 markh
1144493 ryanvm
1144493 ryanvm
1144493 twalker
1145049 wkocher
```

The code is:

```
dataframe <- read.csv("try.csv", header = TRUE)
 i <- 1 
while(i < nrow(dataframe)) {  
   print(dataframe$who[i])  
     i <- i + 1 
 }
```

Output is

```
[1] dtownsend
Levels: dtownsend jorge markh ryanvm twalker wkocher
[1] dtownsend
Levels: dtownsend jorge markh ryanvm twalker wkocher
[1] wkocher
Levels: dtownsend jorge markh ryanvm twalker wkocher
[1] wkocher
Levels: dtownsend jorge markh ryanvm twalker wkocher
[1] jorge
Levels: dtownsend jorge markh ryanvm twalker wkocher
```

Answer (score 2):

R has a data type called `factor` ([read more here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html)) which is causing this behavior.  The "levels" are allowable values, and are the default data type for strings.  The solution is relatively simple:

```
dataframe <- read.csv("try.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
## show datatypes
lapply(dataframe,class)

 i <- 1 
while(i < nrow(dataframe)) {  
   print(dataframe$who[i])  
     i <- i + 1 
 }
```

The other solution is to use a package like [`readr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr) that avoids the use of factors by default.

**EDIT:** If you *need* factors, you can always print with `print(as.character())` to make things look nicer.